# how to replace Characters with numbers javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to replace every Characters with number from 0 to 5 
to make `var string = "abcdef";` turn into `"01245"`
i tried this code but result was not what i want

```
var text = "abcdef";
var num =0;
var tx;
var res;
for (var char in text) {
    tx = text[char];
    res= text.replace(tx,num);
    num = num+1;
    console.log(res);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
String.prototype.charNumReplace=function(){
    var newstr="";
    var self=this.toLowerCase();
    for(var i =0;i<self.length;i++){
        newstr+=self.charCodeAt(i)-97;
    }
    return newstr;
}
```